# Bash script: Open Python, execute some lines, then let user take control

Tags: python, bash

I have a Python program, A.py, that creates binary data upon completion. To help users analyze the output, I want to add a small script, B.sh, to the output directory that fires up a Python console and executes some commands, C, that load the data and prepare them such that a user sees what is available. After executing C, the script B.sh should keep the Python console open.

**First attempt at B.sh:**

I figured out that

```
#!/bin/sh 
xterm -e python
```

opens a Python console and keeps it open but doesn't execute anything within that console.

**Second attempt at B.sh:**

I figured out that

```
#!/bin/sh
xterm -e python -i C.py
```

executes C.py (I'd prefer not to have to write an additional file for the startup commands, but I could live with that) and keeps the window open, but doesn't show what was done. More specifically, the user would be presented with the outputs of C, but not the command that were used to achieve the outputs.
 Instead,I'd like the user to be presented with a console like this:

```
>>> [info,results] = my_package.load(<tag>)
>>> my_package.plot(results)
>>> print(info)
  <output>
>>> my_package.analyze(results)
  <output>
>>>
```

Comment: You could just print the results and the instructions for the user.

Comment: `expect` lets you programmatically pass some input, then hand control back to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Save this in a file called `demo.tcl`

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect -f

# Spawn Python and await prompt
spawn /usr/local/bin/python3
expect ">>>"

# Send Python statement and await prompt
send "print('Hello world!')\n"
expect ">>>"

# Pass control to user so he can interact with Python
interact
```

Then make it executable with:

```
chmod +x demo.tcl
```

And run with:

```
xterm -e ./demo.tcl
```

In the picture, you can see I went on after the "Hello world" to print the system version info.

[image]

Your paths for **Python** and **expect** may be different, so check and alter to suit.

---

For anyone who happens to be using macOS (a.k.a. OSX), you can install `expect` with **homebrew** as follows:

```
brew install expect
```

And, since Macs don't ship with X11 any more, rather than install XQuartz and run `xterm`,  you can start a new Terminal and run the Python in there quite simply with:

```
open -a Terminal.app demo.tcl
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by user @pask I simply printed the commands before executing them.
Furthermore, I added a `-c` switch to be able to put the Python commands directly in `B.sh` instead of having to write a file `C.py`

Here is the `B.sh` I am using now:

```
#!/bin/sh 
xterm -e python -i -c "print('>>> import my_package');import my_package;print('>>> [info,results] = my_package.load()');[info,results] = my_package.load()"
```